# Term for disrespecting people with lower social condition

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called if I have a good social condition (education, money, etc.) and I disrespect people with a lower condition?

Comment: Are you looking for a verb?

Comment: Hi Moataz. Can you provide more context for where you want to use this word or phrase? Can you also tell us what words or phrases you think might fit but are unsure of?

Comment: Do you have a particular way your are disrespecting them? This question seems quite broad to me.

Comment: 'kind of a jerk'?

Comment: well what am I doing,disrespecting people (verb). Another example, if I'm disrespecting certain social class then I'm a ....?

Comment: @Mitch while that's true (and made me snicker), he was looking for something more specific. A hypothetical person would also be 'kind of a jerk' if they threw small animals at blind people, but might not be snobbish, elitist, etc.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- snobbery
- snootiness
- classism
- elitism (*or* élitism)

Comment: I've seen `elitist` used to describe someone fitting those characteristics quite often.

Comment: @TimPost, The word "elitist" sounds way too *elite*. "Snob" is much much more apt. (Contrast *"I'm a elitist and nothing's wrong with it! "* vs *"I'm a snob and nothing's wrong with it! "*)

Answer (score 34):

The words that came immediately to mind were [*condescension,*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/condescension) which means patronizingly superior behavior or attitude, or [*disdain*,](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disdain) which means a feeling or show of superiority and dislike; contempt; scorn.

There are many other words for [the belief that you are better than others](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/The-belief-that-you-are-better-than-other-people).

Comment: I'd have also marked your answer as the right one. But I can only mark one answer. Yours is great as well. thanks

Comment: OP asked for the behaviour of people high on the ladder; the worst disdain I ever encountered was from somebody who had neither money nor education, and despised people 'born with a silver spoon in their mouth'. Reverse snobbery can be as bad as the other kind. But *condescension* is good.

Comment: @TimLymington hope you mean that the word condescension is good. Not the act itself. ;)

Comment: "Isn't it obvious? The prisoner must have escaped down the back staircase.", Tom said condescendingly.

Answer (score 19):

That would be an example of *snobbery*. I'd say you were being a [snob](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snob)

> ***snob***: A person who seeks to be, or is, a member of the upper classes and looks down on lower classes, such as the middle class and the poor. More generally, an egotistical person who often thinks of people as inferior, particularly anyone not being within their clique or class

Comment: I upvoted this because I think it the best answer, and you provided a definition.

Answer (score 9):

In general, you are *bigoted* or are a *bigot*: you treat members of some demographic group as inferior to yourself, especially to the point of intolerance or even hatred.

Specifically, you are *classist*; you are intolerant of members of unequal social status. Understand that you can be on the lowest rungs of the social ladder and be a classist, regarding those of higher wealth as inferior to yourself; many of us actually do regard stereotypical "old money" types with disdain when they display their naivete of and inability to function in the "real world" without all of the conveniences and assistance their money can buy.

More specifically, you are *elitist* or an *elitist*; you aspire to social classes higher than your own and are intolerant of lower social classes than your own (or even of your own social class). You may be termed a *social climber* if you aspire to advance quickly to higher social levels, especially by association with members of that class.

Your actions may make you *snobbish* or a *snob*; you rebuff, avoid or ignore things or people you perceive as inferior, especially to the point of offense or vulgarity.

You may also be an *aristocrat*; of the belief that those in superior social standing are the most fit to rule over all (which is self-reinforcing; those in leadership positions typically gain wealth and celebrity from being in the position). While the connotation of the word implies no inherent disrespect, most aristocrats are in superior social standing themselves, in which case the person asserts themselves to be superior to lower classes by esposing this belief.

Comment: The word 'aristocrat', though members may well show disrespect to nonmembers, does not imply any inherent disrespect.

Answer (score 4):

Another useful term is *[high-hatting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/high-hat)*, which means treating in a condescending or supercilious manner.  [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/high+hatting) lists verb *high-hat* as a synonym of verb condescend.

*[Supercilious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supercilious)*, by the way, means “arrogantly superior; showing contemptuous indifference; haughty”. *[Arrogant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arrogant#Adjective)* typically means “having excessive pride in oneself, often with contempt for others”.  Noun *[contempt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contempt#Noun)* is similar in meaning to nouns *scorn* or *disdain*.

Answer (score 2):

You could also say that you are either [looking down your nose or turning up your nose](http://throwgrammarfromthetrain.blogspot.com/2012/03/turn-up-your-nose-or-turn-it-down.html) at people you consider to be your inferiors.

Comment: yes but what you be called in this case? you looking down your nose, so you are a ...?

Comment: Well, I'd say someone who looks down their nose is arrogant, but that's not specific enough for the question.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience its called discrimination.

Comment: I'd consider 'discrimination' too ambiguous.  Aside from a formal perspective I'm not sure people would literally say "I discriminate against people of a lower class", unless the intention was to explicitly state disrespect or insight camaraderie amongst other snobs.

Answer (score 0):

What about `condescending`? It means *acting in a way that betrays a feeling of patronizing superiority*. Reference: [*define: Condescending* in google](https://www.google.com/search?q=defienL%20condesending&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=RK1&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=define%3a%20condescending&oq=define%3a%20condescending&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.2439.3549.2.3906.3.3.0.0.0.0.204.366.2j0j1.3.0.les;..0.0...1c.VaCn5jn79N0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=3c711fb061ac048&biw=1920&bih=892)

Answer (score 0):

You are a classist (Prejudice or discrimination on the basis of social class, according to Wikipedia).

Answer (score -2):

There is also a slang term, *diss*, which is just short for *disrespect.*

> "Are you dissing me, man?"

Comment: That's not specific to this situation, though.

Comment: haha, what's the noun of that? dissisnt? :)

Comment: @MoatazElmasry: I believe it's "a diss".

Comment: cool. didn't even know there was a noun for that. thnx